# How to use Prometheus' JMX exporter java agent to collect custom metrics

Tags: java, jmx, prometheus

I'd like to use Prometheus' JMX exporter to collect custom application metrics using Prometheus. I have an application that I've packaged into a jar file `ApplicationToMonitor.jar`-- it exposes port 8989 and declares Prometheus metrics, but doesn't expose an end-point for prometheus to scrape (from what I've read, the prometheus javaagent takes care of this).

I'm not sure what the `configuration.yaml` file should look like. Also, why is it recommended that one use the `shaded.io.prometheus` library (and register new metric variables under the default registry) as opposed to the regular `io.prometheus` library and not using a registry at all?

I'm referencing the [Prometheus JMX exporter documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter), just simply not understanding the aforementioned components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would only use the JMX exporter for code you don't control that's exposing JMX metrics. In this case you need to add some exposition per https://github.com/prometheus/client_java#http. The `HTTPServer` is simplest.