# exporting custom metrics through prometheus jmx exporter

Tags: jmx, prometheus, jmx-exporter

I can see jvm, process, java etc metrics on a /metrics endpoint when using the jmx_exporter but not the custom metrics I have exposed through JMX.
When I remove the agent and add a jolokia agent, I can see those custom metrics without problem on Jolokia's exposed endpoint in JSON format. That proves it exists.

jmx exporter agent config

```
rules:
- pattern: ".*"
```

I have scoured through stackoverflow and google groups. Many people have raised similar issues but I can't see a solution.
Any help on why this is not working as expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Prometheus' JMX exporter java agent to collect custom metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51038770/how-to-use-prometheus-jmx-exporter-java-agent-to-collect-custom-metrics)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a **whitelist** entry with a pattern for the object names of your custom JMX Beans.

---

**Example**: Assume domain `foo`, then adding the following to your JMXExporter configuration YAML at top level

```
whitelist: ["foo:*"]
```

will print all the metrics for the beans in the `foo` domain.

---

**Sidenote**: I found it kind of tricky to work with `pattern` entries in the rule set, so I'm gonna add my findings in case you run in this follow up problem.

So, the pattern string for the `pattern` entries in the `rules` section must apply to a specific normalized representation for bean metrics ([see documentation](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter#pattern-input)):

```
domain<beanpropertyName1=beanPropertyValue1, beanpropertyName2=beanPropertyValue2, ...><key1, key2, ...>attrName: value
```

If you provide a `pattern` entry in a rule item, this is used in [JMXCollector.java](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/collector/src/main/java/io/prometheus/jmx/JmxCollector.java) (line 174-175) to create a regex pattern as follows

```
if (yamlRule.containsKey("pattern")) {
    rule.pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*(?:" + (String)yamlRule.get("pattern") + ").*$");
}
```

`JMXCollector` uses this to check if your rule set applies to a given bean (or otherwise apply the default exposition formatter).

JMXExporter will aid you a little in constructing a pattern matcher by providing the normalized format in the `HELP ...` line if you let it use the default formatter (by **not** adding an entry to the `rules` section). If you do a run with no rules, you can copy the normalized bean metric representation and use this to define a matching pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial and i was able to
https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/monitoring-jmx-enabled-java-applications-with-prometheus/

i used this config just as a starting point for the jmx export to show its information on its metrics page.

```
---
jmxUrl: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:5555/jmxrmi
startDelaySeconds: 0
ssl: false
rules:
- pattern: 'com.company.monitoring:*'
  name: consumer
  value: 3
  valueFactor: 0.001
  labels: {}
  help: "Cassandra metric"
  cache: false
  type: GAUGE
  attrNameSnakeCase: false
```